# Java- Hash Map - Data Grouping

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, treemap

Is there a way we can group it as per below output

**inputData json**

```
    [

 {
    'Car': 'BWM',
    'Country': 'Germany',
    'Amount': 13469,
    'Dateof Purchase':20-08-2020
    
 },
 {
    'Car': 'Audi',
    'Country': 'Germany',
    'Amount': 14469,
    'Dateof Purchase':10-01-2020

 }
 {
    'Car': 'Telsa',
    'Country': 'American',
    'Amount': 11449,
    'Dateof Purchase':15-12-2020

 }
]
```

**output**

```
Germany -27938  <-- Total Amount
    BWM : 13469 
    Audi: 14469

American-11449 <-- Total Amount
    Telsa 11449
```

I tried using the below code, but only able to get Car Country Total

```
        Map<String, Integer> Total_Vech = listData.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Vech::getbycountry,
                    Collectors.summingInt(Vech::getsAmount)));
```

Any help would be helpful !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a custom data structure:

```
class CountryStats {
    private int amount;
    private Map<String, Integer> cars = new HashMap<>();

    void addCar(String car, int amount) {
        this.amount += amount;
        this.cars.merge(car, amount, Integer::sum);
    }

    CountryStats merge(CountryStats country) {
        country.cars.forEach(this::addCar);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you can collect them like this:

```
Map<String, CountryStats> statsByCountry = data.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(data -> data.getCountry(), Collector.of(
                CountryStats::new,
                (stats, data) -> stats.addCar(data.getCar(), data.getAmount()),
                CountryStats::merge)));
```

Comment: Still not working .. right now am getting error

error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
        Map<String, CountryStats> statsByCountry = listData.stream().collect(
                                                                            ^
    lower bounds: Map<String,Country.CountryStats>,Country.CountryStats,Object
    lower bounds: Country.CountryStats
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>collect(Supplier<R>,BiConsumer<R,? super T>,BiConsumer<R,R>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream

Comment: @AndroidGod I forgot the grouping part. Updated.